# Nativescript - The Launch Screen has a quality loss when the release version it's generated (android)

Tags: nativescript

I'm making an app with Nativescript, and when I'm in debug mode the quality of the launch screen image is alright, but when I make the release version, I don't know why the launch screen appears like rounded and with a very poor quality.
There is some way to build the release version without zipping or rezising the images or assets? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use http://images.nativescript.rocks to generate your images.  The issue might be that you have images of the wrong sizes in your resources and so they will look poor on real devices...

Comment: No, but I paid attention to the sizes of the images, besides when I run the project un debug mode the images look fine so it is a release problem.

Comment: Last time I looked at the build chain, the build for release images was the same as the build for the debug images.   The only difference was the signing of the app.     It is possible that something has changed in the last couple versions, but seems unlikely.  

I would really check the image sizes; if they are wrong they will look poor...